# Terminal Command or Apple Script to run XCode?

Tags: xcode, build, applescript, remote-access

Is is possible to make XCode run by executing an AppleScript or some sort of terminal command?

Can you pass XCode startup arguments, like a project to open, or to build a project on startup?

**Edit:**

Please excuse my laziness, but Apple Script samples are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly simple to run Xcode from the Terminal: `open -a Xcode` to simply open it, or `open yourproject.xcodeproj` to open your project in Xcode. As for getting it to build on startup, you'd probably have to turn to AppleScript for that:

```
tell application "Xcode"
    build
    launch
end tell
```

Comment: Great starting point, for sure.  I'll need to verify and get back to you.